# "only real words" in Russian - Только настоящие слова?

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения

When you define someone, for example say to a girl that you have a beautiful smile(У тебя красивая улыбка) and she says: oh thanks you can answer her: "**only real words!**"
So is it correct sentence in this situation ?
"**Только настоящие слова!**"

Comment: No, and I don't think that there is anything widely used besides "пожалуйста".

Comment: @Dmitriy , as you see, I think Я только сказал правду. very good answer

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the expression "only real words"? Have you translated it from some other language?

Comment: @WorldLover All this romantic stuff never was my strength. Personally I don't like this phrase and I would never use it (in such situation). BTW, there is also a quotation from Bulgakov's "The Master and Margarita": "Правду говорить легко и приятно", but it was said in another context...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it might sound like this

> – У тебя красивая улыбка. 
>   – Спасибо.
>   – Не за что. Я только говорю/сказал правду.

Answer (score 5):

When someone thanks you for a compliment you have paid them, it's natural to respond like this:

> У тебя красивая улыбка. - Спасибо! - `Пожалуйста` / `Не за что` (stress *не* to mean you're welcome).

If you really want to stress that your compliment is only natural because you are stating a fact, you may want to say `это - факт` or `констатирую факт`. Note that the most common way to respond to thank you is saying  `пожалуйста`  or `не за что`.

Answer (score 4):

Also for stating that your compliment is truth you can use:

Правда, только правда и ничего, кроме правды!

И это чистая правда.

Факты говорят сами за себя.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of conversation the closest equivalent I can imagine would be:

> – У тебя красивая улыбка. – Спасибо. – Нет, правда!

Other examples (e.g. sentences involving `факт`, `сказал правду`) sound too heavy/formal for that, and (to be honest) they still look like an attempt to just translate the corresponding English example w/o considering if they talk like this in Russian at all.

Comment: "The color of the iris of your eyes is close to #22A7F0, and this color is known to look pleasant for the majority of human species." - this is also a compliment. But we do not speak like that! :)